# [quick question] what is color descption and <format> in SDF?

Tags: gazebo, gazebo-camera, gazebo-sensor

[image: Gazebo Answers logo]

hi

I have quesiton about the  tap.
The  tap is under:

```
<sensor> 
     <image>
            <format>
```

According to Gazebo Sdf documentation

```
 Description of <format> :

(L8|R8G8B8|B8G8R8|BAYER_RGGB8|BAYER_BGGR8|BAYER_GBRG8|BAYER_GRBG8)
Required: 0    Type: string    Default: R8G8B8
```

If I want the color to be only black or white, which format should I choose?

Thank you all

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.gazebosim.org/question/3470/%5Bquick-question%5D--what-is-color-descption-and-%3Cformat%3E-in-sdf?/) by [gazer](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/344/gazer/) on Gazebo Answers with karma: 5 on 2013-07-04

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Gazebo Answers logo]

try `L8` for grayscale images

---

Originally posted by [iche033](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/58/iche033/) with karma: 1018 on 2013-07-10

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0